# How to fetch data from website without API

Tags: php, database

I want to fetch all current and future courses form this website http://www.scfhs.info/cme_pd/search/index.php for example this queries http://www.scfhs.info/cme_pd/search/do_search.php to my iOS app , unfortunately they don't have an API.

How to get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out https://www.parsehub.com/ this will help you for sure

Answer (score 2):

I've done this for a project, search for html scraping. There are a tools to do it that vary depending on your platform. [Here is a start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping). Unfortunately if the page changes you have problems. In my case the pages would update in an inconsistent manner. It looks like most of the data you want is in option tags; that should make it easy to parse.

I would have made this a comment, but I'm not worthy yet.

Comment: If you have an actual answer to the question (which you do), why consider making it a comment? :)

Comment: It didn't feel like a complete answer to me, was hoping to point the asker in the right direction. Thanks :)